# Ruby 1.9.2p290 URL regex sometimes hanging / breaking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am doing client side validation in my Rails app with the jQuery validate plugin. I wanted to also validate on the server side with the exact same regex, so I copied the regex from the library and set it up as a constant in my Customer model, which has the website attribute requiring a valid url.

While the regex generally works, if the string I am matching against is too long, it hangs indefinitely. When I run it through Rubular, I get the following error:

```
Rubular suspects this regex will take forever to parse. Regexes of this sort make Rubular sad. Adjust the regex or else wait a few minutes and try again.
```

I know next to nothing about regexes, so I was wondering if anyone noticed anything glaringly wrong with this regex being used in a Ruby context. It would be really nice if Rubular explained which part of the regex raised the warning.

```
class Customer
    URL_REGEX = /^(((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:)*@)?(((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))|((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.?)(:\d*)?)(\/((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)+(\/(([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)*)*)?)?(\?((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|[\uE000-\uF8FF]|\/|\?)*)?(#((([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(%[\da-f]{2})|[!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=]|:|@)|\/|\?)*)?$/i

    validates :website, format: { with: URL_REGEX }, allow_blank: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
end
```

Just in case the regex is hard to see, here is a link: https://gist.github.com/mackshkatz/5437179

Comment: Why don't you use `URI.parse` and the usual `URI` methods?

Comment: I had never explored the URI module until now, but I now see that is an option as well, however, using the builtin regex of the module works fine in my case. Thanks though.

Comment: Keep in mind that the regex will allow things (such as userinfo) that are valid in a URL but you probably don't want to allow. Using URI will make it easy to clean up the URLs.

Comment: +1 @muistooshort. Don't reinvent a wheel unless you know what you are doing. URI or [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable), know how to tear apart and reassemble URLs, and do it according to the specs. Well, Addressable::URI is better than URI at that but for your purposes URI is fine.

Comment: @theTinMan: I tend to think that **all** URLs should be disassembled, cleaned up and normalized, and then reassembled before storage. And doing the same validation and cleanup in two different ways in the client and server code is actually a feature.

Comment: Agreed. I used to normalize them before storing when I wrote an RSS aggregator, and when writing spiders. Doing otherwise is madness and leads to falling down a very deep rabbit hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to provide the regex. You can use one that's in Ruby stdlib in  URI.

Just do:

```
require 'uri'
class Customer

   validates :website, format: { with: URI::regexp }, allow_blank: true, length: { maximum: 255 }
end
```

Also the URL must start with `http` or `https`. So you might need to add it if the string does not start with either.

Comment: Awesome, although we are no longer using the same regex as the client side, this is much cleaner, thanks for the insight into this module.